# sql if date equals today than add AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT e.event_name, e.event_start_date, e.event_start_time, e.post_content
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}em_events e
        WHERE e.event_status = '1'
        AND e.event_start_date >= '{$date_sever}'
        AND e.event_start_time >= '{$time_sever}'
        ORDER BY e.event_start_date ASC
```

i want to run this line `AND e.event_start_time >= '{$time_sever}'` only if `AND e.event_start_date = '{$date_sever}'`

any idea how?

Comment: look up CASE in the mysql manual. Might do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test both conditions using OR operation.

```
    SELECT e.event_name, e.event_start_date, e.event_start_time, e.post_content
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}em_events e
    WHERE 
        e.event_status = '1' 
      AND
        e.event_start_date > '{$date_sever}'
      OR 
        (e.event_start_date = '{$date_sever}' AND e.event_start_time >= '{$time_sever}')
    ORDER BY e.event_start_date ASC
```

It will test if the first expression is GREATHER than `{$date_sever}`. If it's not GREATHER, OR will be called to test if the expression is EQUAL `{$date_sever}` AND the second expression will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
SELECT e.event_name, e.event_start_date, e.event_start_time, e.post_content
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}em_events e
    WHERE e.event_status = '1'
    AND e.event_start_date >= '{$date_sever}' 
    AND (e.event_start_time >= '{$time_sever}' 
        OR e.event_start_date > '{$date_sever}') 
    ORDER BY e.event_start_date ASC
```